# Hide DIV when clicked outside

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form system which is dynamically generated.

**The code below is the button which calls the calendar.**

```
<input id="btn1_0" type="button" value="☵" class="rsform-calendar-box btnCal rsform-calendar-button btn btn-default" onclick="RSFormPro.YUICalendar.showHideCalendar('cal1_0Container');">
```

Here's the div which shows up when the above button is clicked. The button toggles  the style `display:none` when **clicked inside the div**:

```
<div id="cal1_0Container" style="clear: both; position: absolute; z-index: 9987;" class="yui-calcontainer single">
Calendar Here
</div>
```

I want to hide the calendar when someone clicks outside of the div too.

**I tried this JS but it won't work as it sets `display:none` to the div. What am I doing wrong?**

```
jQuery(document).click(function(event) {
    if ( !jQuery(event.target).hasClass('yui-calcontainer')) {
         jQuery(".yui-calcontainer").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: let me know if my answer was helpful to you .

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind a click event to the document. Bind it to the body.

```
jQuery('body').click(function(event) {
    if ( !jQuery(event.target).hasClass('yui-calcontainer')) {
         jQuery(".yui-calcontainer").hide();
    }
});

or

jQuery(document).on('click', 'body', function(event) {
    if ( !jQuery(event.target).hasClass('yui-calcontainer')) {
         jQuery(".yui-calcontainer").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried both your solutions and the result is the same. Once I add your JS, the default status changes to `<div id="cal1_0Container" style="clear: both; position: absolute; z-index: 9987;display:none" class="yui-calcontainer single">Calendar Here</div>` so the button doesn't work anymore as the `display;none` comes into play by default.

Comment: It's adding display none, therefore this JS code is working, so something else is causing it. I'm not familiar with YUICalendar, but you could try calling the same showHide function that is on the button (RSFormPro.YUICalendar.showHideCalendar('cal1_0Container')) in the JS when the target has the "yui-container" class.

Comment: the div is also called by a button with his function: `onclick="RSFormPro.YUICalendar.showHideCalendar('cal1_0Container');"` which stops working when i add your javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some trick like this  ,
check this code below

```js
$(document).dblclick(function (e)
                                {
                var container = $(".yui-calcontainer");
                if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
                    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
                {
                    container.hide();  /// or container.toggle();  to show/hide

                }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="height:100% ; width:100%;";>

        <div id="cal1_0Container" style="clear: both; position: absolute; z-index: 9987;" class="yui-calcontainer single">
            Calendar Here
        </div>
    </body>
```

use `container.toggle();` for show/hide

let me know if it this is helpful to you .

This was my HTMl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).dblclick(function (e)
                                {
                var container = $(".yui-calcontainer");
                if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
                    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
                {
                    container.toggle();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="height:100% ; width:100%;";>

        <div id="cal1_0Container" style="clear: both; position: absolute; z-index: 9987;" class="yui-calcontainer single">
            Calendar Here
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where would I add `container.toggle();`? I can't change the generated form! I can only use the id or class of the form available.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Really appreciate it and voted up. However, you didn't understand my question :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use the YUICalendar library, in which case it might benefit to take a look at the official documentation @ https://developer.yahoo.com/yui/calendar/

I found an example that might accomplish what you're trying to achieve: https://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/calendar/calcontainer_clean.html

Answer (score 0):

When you click on button you will see the div and when you again click the button 
div closed and when div is open and you click outside the div ...div 
       closed...

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#privacy').toggle();
    $('#privacybutton').click( function(e) {
        // stops link from making page jump to the top
        e.preventDefault();
        // when you click the button, it stops the page from seeing it as clicking the body too
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('#privacy').toggle();
    });
    $('#privacy').click( function(e) {
        // when you click within content area, it stops the page from seeing it as clicking the body too
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('body').click( function() {
        $('#privacy').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer a bit and clarify according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

```
 $("body").on('click', function (e) {
    var ignoreContainer = $(".feeling_menu_trigger"); //you can add 
 //.feeling_menu_container class if you want to keep container on when user 
  //click inside of container e.g  
 $(".feeling_menu_trigger,.feeling_menu_container")
    if (!(ignoreContainer.is(e.target) || 
     ignoreContainer.has(e.target).length)) {
        $(".feeling_menu_container").hide();
    }
  });
```