# Javascript function return nothing

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a Javascript function like this in my HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function randomNumber() { 
        return Math.random();
    }
</script>
```

And within a same file i have some php forloop.

I am generating some `<tr>` from the loop
and inside a loop i want to make the call to the javascript function but its not returning anything.

Can anyone please tell me if i am doing anything wrong ?

here is my php for loop.

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
?>
<tr> 
    <td> <?php echo $i; ?> </td>
    <td> <script>randomNumber();</script> </td>
</tr>
<?php 
} ?>
```

Comment: You are calling it, it is not going to actually render anything Add a console.log in the method, you will see it being called.

Comment: Just asking, why not create random number in PHP? And in your case, you are just returning, where are you printing?

Comment: actually  this is similar to my requirement , and i have only this way to do it. i dont have other option

Comment: *"but its not returning anything"* - apart from the missing `<table></table>` tags; this runs (to a certain extent). How are you running this as; `http://localhost` or straight in the browser as `file:///`?

Comment: `document.write()` is an option, not great, but an option.

Comment: what is console showing up

Comment: Let me tell you my requirement. 

I have a javascript function  with the 2 parameters (epochTIme , timezone);    if i call that javascript function and pass the epochtime  it return me with the proper dateformat with converting that time to my local machine,   reason  i  need to do this is only the client side script can get the  local machine timezone ,  using serverside i cant .. so

Comment: The fact that the OP doesn't know how to use javascript yet doesn't mean he asked a low quality question. So please stop downvoting it.

Comment: People: read =>>> ***"but its not returning anything"***

Comment: Why don't you used PHP random instead?

Comment: @Fred-ii- well I think by not returning anything = I am not seeing anything rendered on the page...

Comment: Agree to what Taha has said.

Comment: @epascarello when running their posted code, I get back `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` so that isn't "nothing". Just not what they're expecting being random numbers.

Comment: again: *"but its not returning anything"* - are you going to respond to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261618/javascript-function-return-nothing#comment73591916_43261618) I left earlier? Because `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` to me, isn't "nothing". @Punit.. and [your comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261618/javascript-function-return-nothing#comment73591972_43261618) that makes your question all that much more unclear.

Comment: *"reason i need to do this is only the client side script can get the local machine timezone , using serverside i cant"* - then you'll have to figure out another way of parsing those PHP directives @Punit.. Because I am sure that you're seeing "code" in HTML source, as opposed to parsed PHP directives.

Comment: I started to think that this is a joke because the OP has 2k points in SO, and he has gained enough points in jQuery or JS. Look at the answer from him here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177510/hide-div-when-clicked-outside/39177737#39177737

Comment: @TahaPaksu I don't think so; see their php tag questions/answers  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:5127330+[php] they know php.

Comment: @Punit.. if you can't run php directives, you'll need a pure html/js solution for this. Btw; have you left the question? You'll need to ping me/others directly if you want to address someone directly as I did here for you. I voted to close your question as unclear; I have now moved on. good luck

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes but think, he knows php, jquery and javascript and he has a problem like this? is it normal?

Comment: @TahaPaksu see my comment just above yours to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 
`document.write()` 
to get output:

```
 <script> document.write(randomNumber()); </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like this, instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(randomNumber());</script>
```

In any case, i discourage the use of that kind of methods, instead implement something like:

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
?>
    <tr> 
        <td> <?php echo $i; ?> </td>
        <td class="random-number"></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var rnTds = document.querySelectorAll("td.random-number");
    for (i = 0; i < rnTds.length; i++) {
        rnTds[i].innerHTML = randomNumber();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you see [their comment here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261618/javascript-function-return-nothing#comment73591972_43261618) Being: *"reason i need to do this is only the client side script can get the local machine timezone , using serverside i cant"*.

Answer (score 0):

change `<script>randomNumber();</script>`

To

```
<script>document.write(randomNumber());</script>
```